# How to automatically convert JSON time strings into Time objects with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, time

When I’m using Ruby to consume a web service API that returns time strings in JSON, I want them automatically converted into `Time` objects (or `DateTime` objects) so that I don’t have do it manually myself.

For example, I want this to output `Time` instead of `String`:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> payload = JSON.generate({ now: Time.now })
=> "{\"now\":\"2018-04-02 13:15:56 -0500\"}"
irb(main):003:0> JSON.parse(payload)['now'].class
=> String
```

I understand that times are not part of the JSON spec. I’m just wondering if there’s a way to configure Ruby’s stdlib JSON parser to automatically parse dates, or if there’s a library that does this for you.

Comment: You should consider selecting the one and only answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Active Support can automatically convert ISO 8601 formatted times into `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects when you set `ActiveSupport.parse_json_times = true`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'active_support/json'
require 'active_support/time'

Time.zone = 'UTC'
ActiveSupport.parse_json_times = true

puts payload1 = JSON.generate({ now: Time.now })
puts payload2 = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode({ now: Time.now })

puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(payload1)['now'].class
puts ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(payload2)['now'].class
```

Which will output:

```
{"now":"2018-04-02 13:19:40 -0500"}
{"now":"2018-04-02T13:19:40.291-05:00"}
String
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Notice how Ruby stdlib’s default time is not parseable by Active Support. Only the ISO 8601 formatted time gets successfully converted. Active Support [uses a regex to detect times](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb#L14). You can [read the tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/test/json/decoding_test.rb) to get a good idea of the time formats that it supports. Looks like it supports ISO 8601, but does *not* support Unix/POSIX/Epoch timestamps.

I was informed of this feature in Active Support when I created [this issue against Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32424).

Some history: Time parsing used to be the default behavior in Rails, but then `ActiveSupport.parse_json_times` was added for people who wanted to turn it off, and then it became turned off by default, so now you have to opt into it.

Comment: Another reason to never ever use Rails/ActiveSupport. Applying a regex to everything in the input just because the developer is lazy enough to convert datetimes manually is insane, ugly and should be avoided by everybody.